# Autocad Commande Bar

Tags: autocad, autocad-scripts

I'm working on an c# app that does some stuff in AutoCAD and I would like to know  how can I control AutoCAD command bar (Editor Bar Command) "Closed" "opened"

Sorry for my English

Comment: [Show us some code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: We can hide the command line, by pressing CTrl + 9 i want to do that with .Net

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24389965/how-can-i-open-autocad-2015-through-the-net-api?rq=1

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.