# Changing Autocad parametric block's parameters from .net

Tags: asp.net, autocad

I would like to pass parameter values to an Autocad parametric block in a .net application.
A simple parameter is "d1" (distance).

I am writing a kind of complex asp.net product comfigurator applciation that shuold generate a 2D dxf file based on the user input. 
I use Unity webgl to render the 3D in the webpage, but i also need to create a dxf file at runtime because a Autocad compatible 2D section is in the requirements.

To avoid to create the section from scratch I found that parametric blocks could be a solution: a designer provides me a very complex parametric block and i pass to it the parameters at runtime so that the output file could be donwloaded.

Somehow two tasks are needed:

1) pass the parameters to a parametric block

2) save it to simple dxf (i am not interested it is a parametric block after parameters have been passed)

I was not able to figure out to perform this in .net.

Comment: I found I was able to edit block scale, and other properties, but in the end couldn't work with parametric blocks from the APIs. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19290030/is-it-possible-to-edit-block-attributes-in-autocad-using-autodesk-autocad-intero

Comment: @reckface could you please provide me a poitner to APIs? What they are exactly? I can not understand from the question you linked why parametric blocks are not usable. Thanks.

Comment: I used the block.GetDynamicBlockProperties(), then iterated through the properties and tried to set values, but there was no effect on the block. I am able to _document.ModelSpace.InsertBlock(coordinate.Point, name, scale, yScale, scale, angleInRadians) and then scale it, but that's all you get

Answer (score 0):

To change the parameters of your dynamic block, you can use [GetDynamicBlockProperties](https://knowledge.autodesk.com/search-result/caas/CloudHelp/cloudhelp/2016/ENU/AutoCAD-ActiveX/files/GUID-16C8768B-2533-45FF-9CFF-FF864AC78202-htm.html) to get the properties, then you can change the value on each property.

There is an example in VBA here: http://visiblevisual.com/jupgrade/index.php/autocad-vb-vba/9-insert-dynamic-block.

To save your drawing to a DXF file, you can use `Document.SaveAs(fileName, AcSaveAsType.ac2000dxf)`

However, if you're building a web site, you should use the [Forge Design Automation API](https://forge.autodesk.com/platform) (formerly known as AutoCAD I/O API) instead of driving an AutoCAD instance (this is not reliable and the [AutoCAD EULA](http://download.autodesk.com/us/FY17/Suites/LSA/en-US/lsa.html) does not allow you to do this). You can also use [Teigha](https://www.opendesign.com/).